# Create dropdown menu with JSON response

Tags: jquery

Ok i am trying to populate combobox with JSON response, something like this...

```
  [{"uid":"95bf721c-8c24-432e-83e4-7233169f23fa","name":"MARKETING I MARKETING MENAD\u017dMENT","selected":false},{"uid":"ed4293ff-9c89-4052-9fec-852d34c6150d","name":"PRODAJA I MENAD\u017dMENT PRODAJE","selected":false}]
```

Numbers should be values, Text is a text, and for 3th parametar i have false/true option. If is true value should have attr selected in dropdown menu.

I am thinking creating tag 
 tag

and with j query add options, with some loop. Maybe someone have idea how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = [{"uid":"95bf721c-8c24-432e-83e4-7233169f23fa","name":"MARKETING I MARKETING MENAD\u017dMENT","selected":false},{"uid":"ed4293ff-9c89-4052-9fec-852d34c6150d","name":"PRODAJA I MENAD\u017dMENT PRODAJE","selected":true}];

var sel = $('<select/>');
for (var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    var obj = arr[i];
    var opt = $('<option/>');
    opt.val(obj.uid).text(obj.name)[0].selected = obj.selected;
    sel.append(opt);
}
```

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/xhh4wqv7/

Comment: What do you mean if all is false?

Comment: in some case i will not have selected value in dropdown menu, in JSON response i will have 3th parametar false for all values

Comment: Oh that's fine then. If you change it to false in the fiddle you will see it defaults to the first one in the select just as a standard select element would with nothing selected.

Comment: my mistacke tnx mate!

Comment: Anytime. ;) Happy to help.

Comment: hello can you help me to implement one more thing?

Comment: Sure. Link to question/issue/fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var tiposItems = "<option value='" + valueSelectOne + "'>" + textSelectOne + "

      $.each(JSONdata, function (i, tipo) {
        tiposItems += "<option value='" + tipo.Value + "'>" + tipo.Text + "</option>";
      });
      $('#yourDDL').html(tiposItems);
```